# Error with owl.carosusel in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, owl-carousel

I am using this [owl.carousel](https://gist.github.com/avtaniket/031877c546e0305c8a64c3c46895a627) directive, The idea of my app is to get a list of items when the user click in each item, I open a modal that shows a list of items depending of id. the first time when I click the first item the carousel appears correctly, after that I close the modal and I go to click the second item and there the carousel fails.

this is my code:

```
$scope.item_click = function(id){
  ServGetItemsById.servicioGetItemsById(id).success(function(data, status){
    $scope.all_items = data.items;
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    modal.style.display = "block";
  })
  .error(function(data, status){            
  })
  .finally(function(){})
}
```

my html

```
<data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel" data-options="owlOptionsTestimonials">
  <div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="i in all_items" class="item">
    <img src="{{i.img}}"/>
    <div>
      <p class="white-text center">{{i.name}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</data-owl-carousel>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'll not pretend to have the answer, but is there any difference if you use `<img ng-src="...` instead of `<img src="...`?

Comment: no there is not problem with that my friend :)

Comment: Again, guessing wildly. But since you use stuff outside angulars scope (document.getElementById) won't angular have difficult picking up on those changes? I'd try a `$timeout(function(){ var modal = document.getElementById('modal'); modal.style.display = "block"; });`, or whatever way you prefer to trigger a scope.$apply.  But that wouldn't explain why it works the first time I guess.

Comment: no my friend I try that and no, i have the same error

Comment: only works when I reload my view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get that directive to work. I'm guessing maybe some angular cache is keeping the element alive even when initCarousel triggers repeatedly. Maybe some older version of angular does not have that problem?

Anyway you can always remove the element and force the directive to create a new one. `ng-if` to the rescue:

```
<div ng-if="all_items.length > 0">
  <data-owl-carousel class="owl-carousel" data-options="owlOptionsTestimonials">
    <div owl-carousel-item="" ng-repeat="i in all_items" class="item">
      ...
    </div>
  </data-owl-carousel>
</div>
```

And in the controller.

```
// Remove items before fetching new ones to triggers the ng-if.
$scope.all_items = []; 
ServGetItemsById.servicioGetItemsById(id).success(function(data, status){
...
```

This defeats the purpouse of that directive imho, but what do you do eh?
And oh, I did try it out this time! http://jsfiddle.net/k988Loru/

Comment: I use angularjs 1.5, for example when I send the id each response give 1 o 2 or 3 items the first time when the modal isshowed the carousel is ok, but when i click the second item the carousel fails and show a list of all item and not horizontal

Comment: YOU ARE CORRECT MY FRIEND THANKS